# Does the black-body radiation formula (Stefan-Boltzmann) change if the photon turns out to be massive?

Tags: visible-light, photons, mass, thermal-radiation

The black-body radiation formula, the [Stefan–Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law), is derived treating photons as massless.

**Questions:**

1. What would the Stefan–Boltzmann law look like if derived assuming that photons have mass?
2. What other common relations are based on the assumption of massless photons?

Comment: To understand how [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan–Boltzmann_law#Derivation_from_Planck's_law) would change you need to start by changing [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Derivation) argument. The first change to the latter is replacing $\frac{hc}{2L}\sqrt{\sum_i n_i^2}$ with $\sqrt{(\frac{hc}{2L})^2\sum_i n_i^2+m_0^2 c^4}$, where $m_0$ is the photon's rest mass.